# Derivative of matrix using Kronecker Product

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

Suppose $ A(p)$ and $B(p) $ are functions which map $ \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} $ to $ \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} $ and
$$F(p)=S(I_{q}\otimes A(p))(I_{q}\otimes B(p))M$$
where $ S,M $ are constant matrices with dimension $ qn\times qn $ and $ qm\times qm $ respectively. How to calculate
$$\frac{d\text{vec}(F(p))}{d\text{vec}(p))}$$

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\,C=AB\,$ and note that 
$$(I\otimes A)(I\otimes B)= I\otimes C$$
Let's also use the convention where an uppercase letter denotes a matrix and a lowercase letter a vector, which are related by vectorization, e.g.
$$a={\rm vec}(A),\,\,\,b={\rm vec}(B),\,\,\,c={\rm vec}(C),\,\,\,etc$$ 
Finally, we'll need the SVD of the rightmost matrix in your function.
$$M = \sum_k \sigma_ku_kv_k^T$$
Break the function into components (corresponding to an SVD component).
$$\eqalign{
F_k &= S(I\otimes C)u_kv_k^T\sigma_k \cr
  &= S\,{\rm vec}(CU_k)\,v_k^T\sigma_k \cr
  &= S(U_k^T\otimes I)\,cv_k^T\sigma_k \cr
f_k &= \Big(\sigma_kv_k\otimes\big(S(U_k^T\otimes I)\big)\Big)\,c \cr
}$$
Now find the derivative of this (vectorized) component matrix.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial p}
 &= \Big(\sigma_kv_k\otimes\big(S(U_k^T\otimes I)\big)\Big)\frac{\partial c}{\partial p} \cr
}$$
And since $F = \sum_k F_k\,$ we have our answer
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}
 &= \sum_k\Big(\sigma_kv_k\otimes\big(S(U_k^T\otimes I)\big)\Big)\frac{\partial c}{\partial p}
}$$
I'll leave it to you to work out the derivative on the far RHS, seeing as you told us nothing about the functional form of $A(P)$ and $B(P)$ and therefore of $C(P)$.